# Как получить дату в js с нужным utc (+3)?

Tags: javascript, дата, utc

Нужно чтобы время возвращалась с +3 часа по utc

Comment: Откуда возвращалось?

Comment: @Эникейщик с сервера, как можно преобразовать дату в utc +3 и имеет ли значение откуда ?

Comment: Если у вас к серверу нет доступа, то никак. На самом деле больше имеет значение для чего. Можно или прибавить к полученному времени три часа или указать часовой пояс +3.

Comment: @Эникейщик к серверу есть доступ, но я например не знаю локальное время и у меня есть дата вида     2020 - 03 - 20T09: 00: 00.000Z, неужели нету метода который преобразовывает в нужный utc, в той же moment js например, и как к дате выше можно прибавить +3?

Comment: Для чего вам нужно это время? Есть метод - нужно указать в формате вывода нужный часовой пояс.

Comment: @Эникейщик чтобы все даты которые сервер отдавал были в utc +3, можете поделится методом?буду очень благодарен)

Comment: в этом нет смысла и даже вредно. И не факт, что вообще возможно. Все даты в работе используются по UTC и форматирование нужно использовать только при выводе на экран. Как вы хотите использовать это время?

Comment: Если в переменной, скажем `date` уже находится текущее время сервера по Гринвичу, никто не мешает вам прибавить к этому времени 3 часа. `date += 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Суть заключается в том, что `js` берём время не с сервера, а с компьютера пользователя. 
Соответственно, если пользователь изменит время на компьютере/смартфоне/планшете, или оно установлено у него не корректно, то и данные Вы получите не корректные.

В Вашем случае, Вы можете использовать получение времени с сервера через `php`, другого ЯП, или фреймворка и так далее, либо получать мировое время по `API`

Добавил пример реализации с комментариями для понимания работы скрипта:

```js
    let plus = 3; // Сколько времени прибавляем
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London', false); // Делаем запрос по Лондону
    xhr.send(); // отправляем
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); // Если статус не равен 200, то выводим ошибку.
    } else {
        let time = xhr.responseText; // получаем текст ответа
        let z = JSON.parse(time).utc_datetime; // Получаем время utc
        let time1 = new Date(z).getTime(); // Переводим в timestamp
        let timestampPlus = time1 + (plus * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Воемя +3 часа
        let timePlus = new Date(timestampPlus); // Переводим во время (Тут надо понимать, что система сама переведёт его в текущую временную зону
        let result = timePlus.toUTCString();  // Переводим в строку UTC;
        console.log(result); // Выводим дату.
    }
```